# SQL Select Statement.?

Tags: sql, database

I want to know the actual difference b/w both select statements written in Stored Procedures??

```
Select COUNT(1) from ref_user where nm_user=@nm_user and password=@password;
```

and

```
   Select * from ref_user where nm_user=@nm_user and password=@password;
```

Please guide me proper as i am new to databases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One will return a count. The other will return the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select COUNT(1) from ref_user where nm_user=@nm_user and password=@password;
```

This one returns the count value from `ref_user` table.

```
Select * from ref_user where nm_user=@nm_user and password=@password;
```

This one returns all [datas] values.

Answer (score 0):

The first query returns the Count of rows in the table where as the second query returns the entire rows from the table.

Answer (score 0):

COUNT function is for counting the number of rows

```
Select COUNT(1) from ref_user where nm_user=@nm_user and password=@password;
```

returns number of records matching with the input conditions

```
 Select * from ref_user where nm_user=@nm_user and password=@password;
```

returns the whole row(s) matching the input conditons